# How to setup UIView touch handler without subclassing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview

How do I capture touch events such as `- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` without subclassing a UIView nor using UIViewControllers.

What happens is that I have a simple UIView created programmatically and I need to detect basic tap events.

Comment: why don't you want to subclass it... Subclass of UIView is ideally same as UIView...

Comment: You can say I am lazy.. but subclass will have more codes/classes/files. I merely wanted to capture the touches, and hope there is a delegate I can assign to the UIView.

Comment: hmm.. same problem here, I don't want to subclass just to receive touch events.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are writing your app for iOS 4, use UIGestureRecognizer. You can then do what you want. Recognize gestures without subclassing.

Otherwise, subclassing is the way to go.

Comment: That's a solution. I can use UIView `addGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer`.

Comment: Side note - that was added in 3.2, so you can use them on an iPad as well.

Answer (score 1):

There's just no reason not to. If you subclass and add nothing it's just a `UIView` called by another name. All you are doing is intercepting those functions that you are interested in. Don't forget you can do `[super touchesBegan:touches]` inside your subclass' `touchesBegan` if you don't want to stop responders up the chain from getting those events too.

Comment: Looks like he knows the answer - touchesBegan, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I don't why you don't want to use the normal method of subclassing a UIView to capture touch events, but if you really need to do something weird or sneaky, you can capture all events (including touch events) before they get sent down the view hierarchy by trapping/handling the sendEvent: method at the UIWindow level.

Comment: This is useful tip, but not what i wanted.

Comment: It's pretty logical that someone wouldn't want to subclass a UIView if there were a way to attach an event handler. It's a stronger design pattern. But if there's no way to do it, there's no way to do it. (Though it appears that UIGestureRecognizer might be the best way to go.)

Answer (score 1):

CustomGestureRecognizer.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CustomGestureRecognizer : UIGestureRecognizer
{
}

- (id)initWithTarget:(id)target;

@end
```

CustomGestureRecognizer.mm

```
#import "CustomGestureRecognizer.h"
#import <UIKit/UIGestureRecognizerSubclass.h>

@interface CustomGestureRecognizer()
{
}
@property (nonatomic, assign) id target;
@end

@implementation CustomGestureRecognizer

- (id)initWithTarget:(id)target
{
    if (self =  [super initWithTarget:target  action:Nil]) {
        self.target = target;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)reset
{
    [super reset];
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];

    [self.target touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [super touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];

    [self.target touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
}

- (void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent: event];

    [self.target touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
}
@end
```

Usage:

```
CustomGestureRecognizer *customGestureRecognizer = [[CustomGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self];
[glView addGestureRecognizer:customGestureRecognizer];
```